# Why does the code skip the setTimeout and only later catch up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

The goal is to create a div in a random location within the bounds of the container, wait 3 seconds then destroy the div; rinse and repeat 3 times. The outcome however, from what I can tell, is that while the setTimeout waits the three seconds, the code continues the 'loop' and only after the 3 seconds does the function inside the setTimeout executes. Did I accidentally create two threads?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var $bug = "<div class='bug'><div>";
        var x = 0;

        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (x > 3) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            r1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 270) + 1);
            r2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 270) + 1);
            $('#container').append("<div class='bug'style='top:" + r1 + "px;left:" + r2 + "px;'></div>")
            x++;

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.bug').remove();
            }, 3000)

        }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has got something to do with event loops and the fact that javascript setTimeout function is non-blocking in nature and is called asynchronous.

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bug').remove();
```

This will remove every `.bug` in on the page. You can fix this by giving it another class with an index:

```
$('#container').append("<div class='bug bug" + x + "'style='top:" + r1 + "px;left:" + r2 + "px;'></div>")
```

And then you can remove the first bug by

```
$('.bug.bug0').remove();
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dmy6khed/)

Comment: I considered this issue, but the goal is to remove the bug generated after a few seconds, so there will never really be an array of bugs, ha, puns.

Comment: @brooklynsweb there is no array of bugs. Look at the js fiddle, just an index on the bugs.

Comment: FelisPhasma: per per your note '.bug' would remove all bugs of said class from the scree. What I responded with is that my goal was to remove the created bug a few seconds after it was created thus never having more than one bug on the screen. In doing so '.bug' essentially removes an array of bugs containing only 1 bug. However my original question pertains to something else.

Comment: @brooklynsweb you remove the first bug 3 seconds after it's created, but your creation loop triggers every second. Try creating a bug every 4 seconds https://jsfiddle.net/dmy6khed/1/. (first bug appears after 4 seconds)

Comment: That is what my original question relates to: since I trigger the deletion of the bug within the 'loop' of the creation of the bug, I would assume, that  3 seconds would pass, the bug would be deleted and only then the loop would start again. Per Sebin's note below, this behavior may have something to do with the non-blocking nature of Javascript.

Comment: @brooklynsweb setTimeout is asynchronous. You are just telling the engine, "in three seconds, do this." The code will not wait for that to happen. One solution would be to call the bug creation code from inside the deletion timeout code.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a timer within a timer and because timers are asynchronous you can't predict what will happen when. In your case, the nested nature of the timers causes a runaway effect.

Actually, there is no need to have `setTimeout` at all.

See comments for explanation:

```js
 $(function() {
 
   function insertRandom(){
     var r1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 270) + 1);
     var r2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 270) + 1);
     $('#container').append("<div class='bug' style='position: relative; top:" + 
                             r1 + "px; left:" + r2 + "px;'>Test</div>")
   }
 
   // Insert the random element immediately
   insertRandom();
   
   var x = 0;  // counter for repetition
 
   // Start code at a regular interval
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
   
      // If we're over the count
      if (x >= 3) { 
        // Stop the code
        clearInterval(timer); 
        
        // Terminate the function
        return;
      }
      
      // Increment the count
      x++;

      // Take out the last inserted elmeent
      $('.bug').remove();
      
      // Put a new element in
      insertRandom();

  }, 3000);
  

});
```

```css
#container { border:1px solid black; width:300px; height:300px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```