# Javascript callback execution not working as per understanding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following callback:

```js
doThis(andThenThis);

function andThenThis() {
  console.log('and then this')
}

function doThis(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('this first')
  }, 500)
  callback()
}
```

I've tried using a callback so that my function would execute after the `setTimeout`, no matter how long the first function takes to perform.
I am expecting it to print: 'this first', followed by: 'and then this'. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: `setTimeout` does not pause your code for the specified time interval. It just schedules the function to happen at that later point, and continues your script. That's why you see `"and then this"` first - because `callback` is called approximately half a second before `"this first"` is logged.

Comment: Here's the common three ways to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qpox21Lu/ (callback, promises, async/await)

Comment: Just call `callback()` after `console.log('this first')` (or whatever the long-running work is) without the `setTimeout`... what's the confusion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the code skip the setTimeout and only later catch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423121/why-does-the-code-skip-the-settimeout-and-only-later-catch-up)

Answer (score 2):

Your code does this:

1. set a timer that will execute a function after 500 ms (this action takes no time)
2. call the callback() function (immediately) that print "and then this"

... after 500 ms:

3. log "this first"

The big mistake is to put the code that should be executed first in the "delayed" function!
This is your code correct to execute the 2 logs correctly.

```js
doThis(andThenThis)

function andThenThis() {
  console.log('and then this')
}

function doThis(callback) {
  console.log('this first')  // this is executed immediately
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback()  // this will be executed after 500ms
  }, 500)  
  // console.log('this first')   // if moved here it is still executed before the callback
}
```

As shown in the comment, if you switch actions 1 and 2, you still have the same result, same logs order (to demonstrate the call to setTimeout() exit immediately).

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

```
function theCallBack(data){
   console.log(data, "From doSomethingmethod")
}

function doSomething(callback){

 //Calling callback after Some operation  
 //Example
    axios.get(url)
    .then(function(response){
         callback(response)
    })
}


doSomething(theCallBack);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use a callback function.

```
function doThis(callback) {
  console.log('this first')
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback()
  }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function doThis(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('this first')
  }, 500)
  callback()
}
```

Should be this:

```
function doThis(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('this first');
    callback();
  }, 500);
}
```

When it's outside of the timeout, it executes immediately. Only things in the timeout wait. Try it out here:

```js
doThis(andThenThis);

function andThenThis() {
  console.log('and then this');
}

function doThis(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('this first');
    callback();
  }, 500);
}
```